# why is bubble sort not working

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

Given some numbers and the amount of numbers, I have to sort them in ascending order, then output how many passes and swaps were done. Why is it not working? Also, I wanted to use a vector for this problem; am i passing the vector into the function and calling it properly?

```
//bubble Sort
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

bool isSorted(std::vector<int> & myData);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myData;
    int length = 0;
    int pass = 0;
    int swap = 0;

    cin >> length;


    int x = 0;

    for(x; x < length; x++)
    {
        int input = 0;
        cin >> input;
        myData.push_back(input);
    }

    x = 1;

    while(!isSorted(myData))
    {
        int trash = 0;
        for(x; x < length; x++)
        {
            if(myData[x] < myData[x-1])
            {
                trash = myData[x];
                myData[x] = myData[x-1];
                myData[x-1] = trash;

                swap++;

            }


        }
        pass++;

    }

    cout << pass << " " << swap;

    return 0;
}

bool isSorted(std::vector<int> & myData)
{

    for(int i = 1; i < myData.size(); i++)
    {
        if(myData[i] < myData[i-1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is "not working" about it? Can you give us an example output vs. desired output?

Comment: `for(x; x < length; x++)`   You loop thought your data once, then never set `x` back to the start  (and you should probably start at zero, not one for your indexing) `for(x=0; x < myData.size(); x++)`   
`

Comment: When I copy paste my code into the environment I have to submit assignment in, the compiler doesn't output anything at all. Nothing. Now that I think about it, even if bubble sort doesn't work it should still give me two zeros since pass and swap were initialized at zero. It doesn't make it any easier that my compiler isn't working so I have to use the environment's. Any suggestions?

Comment: The while loop isn't breaking probably

Comment: Your for loop is only making one pass, so `isSorted()` will never be true

Comment: You should not make a full scan of the data every iteration just to see when it is sorted. The algorithm knows when it has finished. Just implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not reset `x` between iterations of bubble sort. What happens is that before the first iteration of your outer loop `x` is equal to one. You then run the inner `while` loop until `x` becomes `length`, and go to the next iteration of the outer loop. By the next iteration `x` is never reset, so it still equals to `length`, so nothing happens on the second iteration, the inner loop immediately breaks without doing any work. You go to the third iteration of the outer loop, and nothing happens again. In particular, your array never becomes sorted, so the outer `while` loop never breaks, and the program never finishes (and never prints anything).

To fix it, just move `x = 1` inside the loop, like this:

```
...
while(!isSorted(myData))
{
    x = 1;
    int trash = 0;
...
```